# update computed column in nhibernate code first

Tags: c#, nhibernate, calculated-columns

I'm using nhibernate code first And I have a computed column.

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
public virtual bool? IsInternal { get; set; }
```

when I'm trying update my object, I received an error: 
The column "IsInternal" cannot be modified because it is either a computed column or is the result of a UNION operator.

Comment: Its a computed column, why would you manually update it? Its like having a column that returns the value of `2 + 4` and trying to set it to `10`, it doesn't make sense... I don't think it should even have a `set` method, but I'm used to working with EF...

Comment: I'm not updating that column. It's updating automatically. If I don't have a set it doesn't show the value of that property in my UI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should set update and insert to false on property mapping and It will solve this problem

```
public virtual bool? IsInternal { get; set; }

Map.Property(p => p.IsInternal, u =>
            {
                u.Update(false);
                u.Insert(false);
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

A computed column doesn't need any update (in most situations, not persisted). It always calculated on the fly, when it is needed. This is why you get this error.

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx):

> A computed column is a virtual column that is not physically stored in
>   the table, **unless the column is marked PERSISTED**. A computed column
>   expression can use data from other columns to calculate a value for
>   the column to which it belongs. You can specify an expression for a
>   computed column in in SQL Server 2016 by using SQL Server Management
>   Studio or Transact-SQL.

Comment: I'm not updating that column. It's updating automatically